# Ranger cd into a folder (and invoke shell)?

Tags: terminal, file-manager, ranger

I'm using [Ranger](https://ranger.github.io/) to navigate around my file system.

Is there a shortcut where I `cd` into a folder without leaving Ranger *(as in open bash with a location of a folder found by navigating in Ranger)*?

Comment: Which folder do you mean by "that"?

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev updated

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I found the answer to this in the [man pages](http://manpages.org/ranger):

> S             Open a shell in the current directory

*Yes, probably should have read through that before asking here.*

Comment: and type `exit` in terminal to go back to ranger

Comment: Doesn't work for me — typing `s cd ~` still leaves me in `/tmp` directory.

Comment: @Hi-Angel when you are browsing directories hit `S` it should leave ranger and go to a new terminal. But if you run `exit` you go back to ranger. You need to use a capital `S` small `s` won't work.

Comment: As an alternative to `exit`, you can go back to ranger by pressing Ctrl-D (`^D`). That types the [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) character, telling the shell you will input no more commands.

Answer (score 37):

Another approach is to have the underlying shell "follow" [`ranger(1)`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/community/ranger/ranger.1.en) around the filesystem so that after navigating to a new directory and `ranger(1)` is quit (or suspended; usually <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) the underlying shell will already be in the same directory `ranger(1)` was quit in.

To do this, have the shell "source" `ranger(1)` either by prefixing the command with the *word* `.` (i.e., the dot or period character) or the *word* `source` on some shells.

```bsh
. ranger
```

Now your shell will "follow" `ranger(1)` around the filesystem.

This works because the `ranger` command (which is python script) has an embedded [`bash(1)`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/bash/bash.1.en) script that is read when sourcing the file. Note that, it only works on [`bash(1)`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/bash/bash.1.en) compatible shells.

From a [comment block in the script](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger.py):

> This embedded bash script can be executed by sourcing this file.
> It will cd to ranger's last location after you exit it.
> The first argument specifies the command to run ranger, the
> default is simply "ranger". (Not this file itself!)
> The other arguments are passed to ranger.

If this becomes your preferred mode to use `ranger(1)` in, add it as an `alias` in your shells initialization script.

```bsh
alias ranger='. ranger'
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 12):

You could also use `:cd /path/to/folder` if you are already in Ranger.

Update: The question has been edited since this answer was given, making it invalid.

Comment: This does NOT invoke the shell in the specified folder.

Comment: But thanks! This is what I was looking for when I google brought me to this page.

Answer (score 11):

You can also do it the other way and use `ranger-cd` to automatically change the directory in bash after closing ranger [with this script](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Integration-with-other-programs#changing-directories).

```
function ranger-cd {
    local IFS=$'\t\n'
    local tempfile="$(mktemp -t tmp.XXXXXX)"
    local ranger_cmd=(
        command
        ranger
        --cmd="map Q chain shell echo %d > "$tempfile"; quitall"
    )

    ${ranger_cmd[@]} "$@"
    if [[ -f "$tempfile" ]] && [[ "$(cat -- "$tempfile")" != "$(echo -n `pwd`)" ]]; then
        cd -- "$(cat "$tempfile")" || return
    fi
    command rm -f -- "$tempfile" 2>/dev/null
}
```

Your shell changes the directory only when you quit ranger with keybinding capital Q (see `map Q` if you want to change this).

I use it with

```
alias r=ranger-cd
```

You can adapt this script to do other things as well, e.g. exit ranger and switch to a vim session in this directory.

Comment: The link in your answer is broken, can you fix it, please?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis updated

Comment: For those who are considering this trick, please also look at @Neurognostic's answer below too. Basically, you can achieve the same thing by sourcing ranger. Thus, running ranger this way works too: `. ranger`

Comment: @laktak Sadly this is not working with zoxide which I use instead of cd :(

Answer (score 1):

```bash
rangercd() {
    tmp="$(mktemp)"
    ranger --choosedir="$tmp" "$@"
    if [ -f "$tmp" ]; then
        dir="$(cat "$tmp")"
        rm -f "$tmp"
        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            if [ "$dir" != "$(pwd)" ]; then
                cd "$dir"
            fi
        fi
    fi
}
bindkey -s '^o' 'rangercd\n'
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is less fancy, and involves a few more moving parts than the others here.

The idea is, when the user presses `S` (the typical binding for 'shell'), map that to a ranger command that writes the current directory to a temporary file.

Then, wrap ranger in a (in my case, `zsh`, but should work on `bash` as well) shell function, which checks if that temporary file exists. If it does, it `cd`s to that directory, and then deletes that file.

Since shell functions execute in the current shell, they *do* change your current directory.

Though its a bit complicated than the other answers here, it doesn't leave the hanging `ranger` instance, and it works well.

So, in `rc.conf`, add the line:

`map S quit_and_cd`

In the `commands.py` (the file where you can create custom ranger commands) file, create that command:

```py
import os
from ranger.api.commands import Command

class quit_and_cd(Command):
    def execute(self):
        with open("/tmp/cd_ranger", "w") as f:
            f.write(os.path.abspath(self.fm.thisdir.path))
        # same as quitall_bang (:quitall!)
        self.fm.exit()
```

Then, in your shell startup (`.zshrc` or `.bashrc`), create a function named ranger:

```bsh
ranger () {
        local LOGFILE='/tmp/cd_ranger'
        # `command ranger` to launch ranger itself,
        # instead of causing an infinite loop with
        # this function calling itself
        command ranger "$@" || exit $?
        if [[ -f "${LOGFILE}" ]]
        then
                cd "$(cat "${LOGFILE}")"
                rm -f "${LOGFILE}"
        fi
}
```

I have these synced up to my dotfiles, see [here](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/dotfiles/tree/master/.config/ranger) and [here](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/zsh/functions/ranger).

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants a python script to do the trick, check out the project [ranger-quit_cd_wd](https://github.com/JohanChane/ranger-quit_cd_wd). It uses a python script instead of shellscript to get the job done.

If you also use `tmux`, check out [ranger_tmux](https://github.com/joouha/ranger_tmux) for an integration solution.